# How to find where is the null pointer exception

Tags: java, mysql

the following code shows a null pointer exception. but I can't find where is it. this is with my sql database. How should I fixed this?

```
       try {
             DefaultTableModel d=(DefaultTableModel) jTable3.getModel();
             for(int x=0;x<d.getRowCount();x++){
                 double npu=Double.parseDouble(jTable3.getValueAt(x, 7).toString());
                 double ns=Double.parseDouble(jTable3.getValueAt(x, 8).toString());
                 double dis=Double.parseDouble(jTable3.getValueAt(x, 9).toString());
                 int qty=Integer.parseInt(jTable3.getValueAt(x, 10).toString());
                 JM.putdata("INSERT INTO stock VALUES('"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 0).toString()+"','"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 1).toString()+"','"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 2).toString()+"','"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 3).toString()+"','"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 4).toString()+"','"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 5).toString()+"','"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 6).toString()+"','"+npu+"','"+ns+"','"+dis+"','"+qty+"','"+jTable3.getValueAt(x, 11).toString()+"')");
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NullPointerException occurs whenever you call a method on null object reference. e.g. say, in your example

```
jTable3.getModel()
```

At runtime, the object reference `jTable3` is not initialize; it means, the above call is more like

```
<null>.getModel()
```

Since the null reference can not handle the method call (the actual *expected* object is not there); so null pointer exception occurs.

**How to detect Nullpointer?**

1. Print the exception in log file/console. For that use a try-catch block in the code like

   ```
   try{
      // your code, which may throw nullpointer.
       }catch(Exception e) { // Just catch all exception
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```
2. Inspect the stacktrace (this is common for any kind of exception, not just Nullpointer)
   Lets take an example:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
>        at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:75)
>        at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:3301)
>        at com.example.va.datasender.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:36)

Line 1: Tell about the exception type- in this case NullPointerException
Line 2: It tells the name of the Java file and exact line number.
Go to the line number and check for all the method call on object reference:
e.g.

```
obj.someMethod();
```

1. Look for a possible case for your program, when obj reference could be Null. If you have difficulty, simply check for null of objects to detect, like

> ```
> if(obj == null){
>   System.out.println("obj is null");
>   }
> ```

**How to avoid NullPointer?**

Please [See Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/05/ava-tips-and-best-practices-to-avoid-nullpointerexception-program-application.html) a good tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a mysql exception but a Java exception. Within the catch body, add this line:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

This will print the line where the exception has been thrown within a list representing its call stack.

You can find more details here: [printStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint in your code and then inspect your variable values line by line.

Setting a Line Breakpoint
To set a line breakpoint, click the left margin of the line where you want to set the breakpoint or click in the line and press Ctrl-F8.
To delete the breakpoint, click the left margin of the line or click in the line and press Ctrl-F8.
If you want to customize a line breakpoint, you can do so through the Breakpoints window.
Choose Window | Debugging | Breakpoints or press Alt-Shift-5. In the Breakpoints window,
right-click the breakpoint and choose Customize

More info: https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/nbfieldguide/Chapter5-Debugging.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Will tell you exactly which line has the NullPointerException